# Can we have both OAuth and Certificate authentication in ASP .NET Core 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authentication

Currently, we have a working OAuth authentication for our ASP.NET Core 5 Web API. We would like to add a certificate authentication as well to be double sure of our caller. Is there a way to have both of them? I tried the below code but it overrides one over the other.

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
.AddAzureADBearer(options =>
{
   options.Instance = aADInstance;
   options.ClientId = clientIdWithScope;
   options.Domain = aADDomain;
   options.TenantId = aADTenantId;
}
)
services.AddAuthentication(
CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCertificate();
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Changing default policy

```cs
// Add authentication schemes before, we already did this, so I would skip this part

// Change default Authorization policy
services.AddAuthorization(cfg =>
    cfg.DefaultPolicy =
        new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
```

`[Authorize]` attribute now would require all http request to satisfied both `CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` and `AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme`, that might be not the behavior we want for all of our endpoint, so, be careful with this approach.

##### Add our own policy

```cs
// Add authentication schemes before, we already did this, so I would skip this part

// Adding our own policy
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ComposedPolicy", p =>
    {
        p.AuthenticationSchemes = new List<string>
            {CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme};
        p.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        p.Build();
    });
});
```

`[Authorize]` attribute behavior now would be untouch, but whenever we want to use our custom policy, we must specify them by `[Authorize(Policy = "ComposedPolicy")]`.

*Just choose the approach that suit the best.*